# Excluding tests from coverage report with sbt coverage

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, scoverage

I have a test that is non-functional, so I do not want it to affect the coverage report. Other than putting it in a separate project, is there a way to exclude it from the report when running

`sbt clean coverage test coverageReport`

As it stands, it is obscuring missing coverage by other tests.

To explain better I've made a [sample project in GitHub](https://github.com/codevineyard/sbt-coverage-example). There are two test classes - MainSpec and DoubleSpec. I've commented out the test in DoubleSpec to show that the test in MainSpec gives 100% coverage. However, it's obscuring that DoubleSpec is "broken". MainSpec is not testing the functionality, only checking the return type.

The example is contrived. I have a much more complex example which I cannot share.

I've tried using [`coverageExcludedFiles`](https://github.com/scoverage/sbt-scoverage/#exclude-classes-and-packages-and-files) but this only excludes source from coverage, not tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider creating a ScalaTest [tag](https://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/tagging_your_tests)

```
import org.scalatest.Tag
object ExcludeFromCoverage extends Tag("ExcludeFromCoverage")
```

based on which to exclude particular tests only when running coverage

```
  "double" should "return an Int" taggedAs ExcludeFromCoverage in {
    ...
  }
```

so now executing using `testOnly` like so

```
sbt clean coverage  "testOnly * -- -l ExcludeFromCoverage" coverageReport
```

will exclude `"double" should "return an Int"` from the coverage report. Note you can still execute all tests with `sbt test`.

---

Given above, then to still run tests tagged with `ExcludeFromCoverage` but not include them in coverage consider defining a custom command like so

```
commands += Command.command("testWithSmartCoverage") { state =>
  "clean" :: 
  "set coverageEnabled := true" :: 
  "testOnly * -- -l ExcludeFromCoverage" :: 
  "set coverageEnabled := false" ::
  "testOnly * -- -n ExcludeFromCoverage" :: 
  "coverageReport" :: 
  state
}
```

Comment: That solves some of it but it doesn't run the MainSpec at all now. I would like the test in MainSpec to run but not be in the coverage report.

Comment: I've got it working by introducing a test script. I've updated the project so that it works. Thanks for the info about test tags, which were the important bit I didn't know.

Comment: Thanks - using custom commands is very neat! I've updated the repo and acknowledged your fantastic help.